# Is there any difference between HttpContext.Current.Request and HttpContext.Request?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-mvc-4, httpcontext

If I want to access Request object in controller action I need to write `HttpContext.Request`, whereas if I want to access the same object in MVC view, I need to write `HttpContext.Current.Request`.
Is there any difference between them?
The problem I am facing is that, the cookies which I set through `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add` in controller action are not being retrieved in `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` collection in an MVC view, though I can see those cookies through javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have to write `HttpContext.Request` in a controller and `HttpContext.Current.Request` on a view is because a controller that you write inherits the abstract class `Controller` that has a property called `HttpContext` that is of type `HttpContextBase`. The view then uses the sealed class `HttpContext` that gives you an httpcontext object for the current request.

> Is there any difference between them?

No. As both give you the same `HttpRequest` object for the current request.

Comment: Ok, the problem I am facing is, I set a cookie in a Controller action, and want to read it in an MVC view but it is showing no value. However, if I try to read it from javascript of the same view, it is showing the value. what could be the solution?

Comment: So if you do: `Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookie_monster", "six-eyed"));` in your controller and do a `<h1>@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["cookie_monster"].Value</h1>` nothing is showing up? And are you even using it that way? Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm mistaken, you write a cookie out to the response, but that cookie is not available on the request until the next request is made (ie, you have to load the same or a new page again to get it to read the cookie). Cookies are not a good way to share information between controller and view, you should use ViewData or ViewBag.

Also, you must make sure that you are not writing to the cookie after you have already output anything, which is one reason that `Response.Write` is not recommended.

The reason the javascript works is that it reads the cookie at the client rather than on the server.