# What is the Difference between HttpContext.Request and Request a .NET Core controller?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060632/is-there-any-difference-between-httpcontext-current-request-and-httpcontext-requ) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547989/difference-between-httpcontext-request-and-request) but they pertain to the legacy .NET Framework.  This question is about the .NET Core.

What is the difference between the two statements below when executed in a controller that inherits from ControllerBase:

```
var request1 = Request;
var request2 = HttpContext.Request;
```

Comment: That's something it seems you could easily figure out yourself. Do they point to the same object? Are they the same type of object? Do they have the same values? Good thing ASP.NET Core is open source, so it took me less than 2 minutes to [find the answer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs) by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same instance of the object [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest).
If you want you look the source code of [ControllerBase](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d7a7c65b2b40a97bb0ba78c07380c46bc5920400/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L35-L43) you can see that only difference is the method to access to object.

Comment: Thank you for a constructive response!